# Can I add a timeline to a Case programatically?

Tags: civicase

Is it possible to Add a predefined Timeline to a Case from a hook, via API or otherwise?  That is, duplicate the effect of a user clicking the "Add Timeline" button in a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can base it on the code found in CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php. You'll need to adjust references to $this, etc.

```
  $session            = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
  $this->_uid         = $session->get('userID');
  $xmlProcessor       = new CRM_Case_XMLProcessor_Process();
  $xmlProcessorParams = array(
    'clientID' => $this->_contactID,
    'creatorID' => $this->_uid,
    'standardTimeline' => 0,
    'activity_date_time' => date('YmdHis'),
    'caseID' => $this->_caseID,
    'caseType' => $this->_caseType,
    'activitySetName' => $params['timeline_id'],
  );
  $xmlProcessor->run($this->_caseType, $xmlProcessorParams);
  $reports = $xmlProcessor->get($this->_caseType, 'ActivitySets');

  CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(ts('Activities from the %1 activity set have been added to this case.',
      array(1 => $reports[$params['timeline_id']])
  ), ts('Done'), 'success');
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just what I needed, thanks Demerit!  For reference for anyone trying to do something similar to what I'm doing, here's code that works for me.  I'm starting with:

$rid = the ID of a recipient of an inbound email

$mid = ID of the case coordinator

...then fetching the person's case, changing the case status, and adding the timeline:

```
   $caseresult = civicrm_api3('Case', 'get', array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'return' => "id, case_type_id",
    'contact_id' => $rid, 
    'status_id' => "Open",
    'is_deleted' => 0,
    'options' => array('limit' => 1),
  ));
  if ( $caseresult['count'] == 1) { //case found, so proceed
    $case_id = $caseresult['values'][0]['id'];
    $case_type_id = $caseresult['values'][0]['case_type_id'];
    //update case status
    civicrm_api3('Case', 'create', array(
      'sequential' => 1,
      'contact_id' => $rid,
      'status_id' => 3,
      'id' => $case_id,
    ));
    $xmlProcessor = new CRM_Case_XMLProcessor_Process();
    $xmlProcessorParams = array(
      'clientID' => $rid,
      'creatorID' => $mid,
      'standardTimeline' => 0,
      'activity_date_time' => date('YmdHis'),
      'caseID' => $case_id,
      'caseType' => 'member_application',
      'activitySetName' => 'timeline_1',
    );
    $xmlProcessor->run('member_application', $xmlProcessorParams);
  }
```

Note that 'member_application' and 'timeline_1' are hard coded.  I found the right values to use by temporarily modifying CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php and adding the Timeline I want to case manually, then looking at the output in my debug.txt file:

```
$xmlProcessor->run($this->_caseType, $xmlProcessorParams);
$file = fopen("/tmp/debug.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, print_r($xmlProcessorParams, TRUE));
fclose($file);
$reports = $xmlProcessor->get($this->_caseType, 'ActivitySets');
```